# What does it mean when you see three dots over a player's head instead of their name?

Tags: destiny

Ordinarily you see a player's name and level as hover text above their head, and sometimes it's three dots.  What do the dots mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an indication that the player is in a menu, interacting/inspecting other players, or interacting with a vendor.

Comment: Or inspecting someone! Like you! Creepers!

Comment: This is why I never wear underpants.

Comment: Or too far to tell.

Comment: @Eben took me a while to get that. Haha